# C++ int variable value

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int intVar =1500000000;
  intVar = (intVar *10)/10;
  cout << "Value intVar equal "<<intVar <<endl;

  intVar =1500000000;
  intVar = (static_cast<double>(intVar)*10)/10;
  cout << "Value intVar equal " <<intVar<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In this example, the first answer must be incorrect (211509811) due limit of variable type **int**, but it isn`t. What is wrong?

Comment: What is a "limit" of variable type int? Did you check the output of `cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`?

Comment: "_In this example, the first answer must be incorrect_" Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior..

Comment: disable optimization and you'll see what you expected

Comment: Undefined behavior does *not* mean that the result must be incorrect. It means the program can do anything, including producing a result, including a result that you would mathematically expect. It can be argued that undefined behavior that appears produces the expected behavior is the most dangerous kind of undefined behavior, or at least the most treacherous.

Comment: a wrong result can still have the correct value (you just cant rely on that)

Comment: @PeterT I suppose you could provide an answer that is more helpful to OP than the current ones. After all there is no overflow at all if you are right, because the multiplication does not even happen.

Comment: @everclear no, the other people are still right, the reason why the compiler is allowed to optimize it out is that it's undefined behaviour. They're technically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you are multiplying by 10 and dividing by 10 on the same line with nothing that can break the compiler optimizations (no function calls, variable assignments, etc.). So any decent compiler will neither multiply nor divide, the same value will be stored, and I guess that is what happened to you.

But if you break that optimization by, say, making the operation in successive calls, it may give the value you seek, e.g.:

```
intVar =1500000000;
intVar*=10;
intVar/=10;
cout << "Value intVar equal "<<intVar <<endl;
```

Possible output:

```
Value intVar equal 211509811
```

[Example](https://ideone.com/4Idu1y)

But note that, in both cases, you are opening the door of Undefined Behavior. If I were you, I would not rely on the compiler optimizations or any lack thereof, especially if you work with different compilers and/or different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

> In this example, the first answer must be incorrect (211509811) due limit of variable type int, but it isn`t. What is wrong?

Your expectation is wrong. The behaviour of signed integer overflow is undefined. There is no requirement for the answer to be "incorrect". After all, there is no "correct" answer for a program that has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your example invokes **Undefined Behavior** (UB), since signed integer overflow occurs.

When UB is invoked you cannot predict with certainty what will happen. That's what happens, thus your prediction is inaccurate. And if you change your prediction completely, since UB is invoked, it will still be inaccurate.

Answer (score -1):

You save 1,500,000,000 in an (signed)int which can hold 2,147,483,647 so you are still within the limits of an singed int. Your operation below that will be erased by the optimizer.

Comment: optimizations are according to the as-if-rule. So an optmization of the `*10)/10` is performed as if there was overflow (assuming `*10` does overflow), thus compiler could as well "optimize" the line to `intVar = 42;`